# Alphanumeric Sorting SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

I have a report that creates a parts list from my MFG software. The part number list currently looks like this:

```
DA100-12
DA100-121
DA100-122
DA100-13
DA100-131
```

I want them to sort taking into account the numeric part at the end like this:

```
DA100-12
DA100-13
DA100-121
DA100-122
DA100-131
```

Does anyone have suggestions on how to accomplish this within a report?

Answer (score 0):

You could split at the `-` and then sort by the last part numerically. One solution would be to do this in the underlying database query already, maybe like this:

```
SELECT PartNo, SUBSTR(PartNo, 1, CHARINDEX('-', PartNo)) AS PN, CONVERT(INT, SUBSTR(PartNo, CHARINDEX('-', PartNo) + 1, LEN(PartNo))) AS NumPart
```

You may need to tweek the `SUBSTR` indices a bit, I can not actually try this right now. Then have SSRS sort by PN and NumPart. The result of the query should look something like this:

```
PartNo      PN      NumPart
---------------------------
DA100-12    DA100   12
DA100-121   DA100   121
DA100-122   DA100   122
DA100-13    DA100   13
DA100-131   DA100   131
```

I'm pretty sure that you can also do the splitting in SSRS itself, too, in the sort expression.

Comment: It's not actually that consistent. I have the parts in many formats. Some are 1234, 1234-1234, AB123-123, AB123-123X, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can also leverage the T-SQL function PARSENAME for this, if there are no '.' characters in your data and if there is always exactly one '-' separating the parts. (Ultimately, you may be better off redesigning things so the two parts of the part name are in separate columns.)

```
select * from Parts
order by 
  PARSENAME(REPLACE(PartName,'-','.'),2),
  CAST(PARSENAME(REPLACE(PartName,'-','.'),1) AS INT)
```

[Click here for a SQL Fiddle repro](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/20a26/1).